# Are there any mods to change the way planes fly in Just Cause 2 PC?

Tags: keyboard, just-cause-2

In Just Cause 2 there are a number of races which involve flying a plane around a course. However I find the keyboard controls (<kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for accelerate/decelerate, <kbd>S</kbd> to pitch the nose up and <kbd>W</kbd> to pitch down, and <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> to roll left and right) very hard to master - I was kind of hoping that it would behave like it did in the Battlefield series. Are there any mods to change the actual controls for flying the plane as the only aircraft mods are overpowered reskinned models of the planes already in the game.

The game is the PC version, ran and updated through Steam to the latest version.

Comment: If you have an Xbox 360 controller, the entire game is vastly improved by its use.

Comment: I've never played the Battlefield series, how do the controls work on it?

Comment: @SteveV. the keyboard is used (w/s) for throttle and a/d for turning in a wide circle, while the mouse is used to bank up/down and "rolling" left and right

Answer (score 3):

On a PC, you can use [JoyToKey](http://www-en.jtksoft.net/), it is a keyboard emulator for joysticks. It converts joystick input into keyboard input (and mouse input).

Use it when you want to control an application with joysticks that doesn't support joystick input.